# How can I create a stretching line with a box attached on a slider with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, draggable, droppable

The line has a box attached to it which is the drag point for sliding and stretching the line.
How can I set the drag point outside the bar and modificate the line?
[image]

Comment: So are you wanting to be able to drag the box up or down and make the red line expand? Or slide the lines left to right?

Comment: I have started this for you. Will finish it later tonight or tomorrow...

http://jsfiddle.net/judsonmusic/Y99MA/26/

Comment: Hi Judson,
thank you. The lines have to slide with the attached boxes left and right. So that the content of the boxes remains readable, it should be movable up and down.

Comment: Maybe the queue()-Function is necessary and the y-position of the line have to be stable. Only length modification and x-positon of the line change. The red line is a scale.

Comment: I have been away on business. Did you ever get this working?